# How to test angular 2 services on the Dart VM?

Tags: dart, angular

I heard that I can test services on the Dart VM (so without browser). I'm wondering how I can do this.

So say I want to test this service:

```
@Injectable()
class MyService {
  String greet = 'Hello world';
}
```

I could test just like this:

```
import 'package:test/test.dart';

void main() {
  var myService = new MyService();

  test('test greet', () {
    expect(myService, equals('Hello World'));
  });
}
```

So this example is very simple, but for more complex service classes, I would like to use angular 2 dependency injection. How could I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To test pure injectable services (i.e. not components) all you need is create an injector that contains dependencies (usually mocks) for the tested class. Here is an example:

```
import 'package:test/test.dart';
import 'package:angular2/angular2.dart';
import 'package:angular2/src/core/reflection/reflection_capabilities.dart';

@Injectable()
class Foo {
  greet() => 'hi';
}

@Injectable()
class Bar {
  final Foo foo;
  Bar(this.foo);
}

class MockFoo implements Foo {
  greet() => 'bonjour';
}

main() {
  reflector.reflectionCapabilities = new ReflectionCapabilities();
  group('MyService', () {
    Injector inj;

    setUp(() {
      inj = Injector.resolveAndCreate([Bar, provide(Foo, useClass: MockFoo)]);
    });

    test('should work', () {
      Bar testSubject = inj.get(Bar);
      expect(testSubject.foo.greet(), 'bonjour');
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: The static method Injector.resolveAndCreate doesn't exist anymore unfortunately